# Echart Custom label in sunburst chart

Tags: javascript, echarts, sunburst-diagram

```
option = {
    tooltip: {},
    series: {
        label: { rotate: 'tangential', },
        nodeClick: false,
        radius: ['15%', '80%'],
        type: 'sunburst',
        sort: null,
        data: [
            {
                name: "sun",
                value: 3456,
                itemStyle: { color: '#814175' },
                label: { formatter: '{b}\n\n{c}' },
                children: [{ name: '', value: 2221, itemStyle: { color: '#a4829d' }, }]
            },


            {
                name: "mon",
                value: 6555,
                itemStyle: { color: '#498ce7' },
                label: { formatter: '{b}\n\n{c}' },
                children: [{ name: '', value: 5001, itemStyle: { color: '#79aefa' }, }]
            },],

    }
};
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcA0o.jpg

This is my chart in the first picture.When i hover the chart the label was hide(second picture).
i need to show all label on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to assign the `formatter` for `emphasis` and `downplay`. You can have different formats for the default label, the label that is hovered and the non-hovered labels

```
series: [
    {
        type: 'sunburst',
        data: [],
        label: {
            formatter: 'E.g. A \n{b}\n\n{c}'
        },
        emphasis: {
            label: {
                formatter: 'E.g. B \n{b}\n\n{c}'
            }
        },
        downplay: {
            label: {
                formatter: 'E.g. C \n{b}\n\n{c}'
            }
        }
    }
]
```